# Limit. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^{p}}{n^{p+1}}$.

Tags: limits

Have you any idea how to find the limit of the following sum: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^{p}}{n^{p+1}}.$$

Stolz-Cesaro? any more ideas?

Comment: I'm not so sure

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Sums_of_pth_powers

Comment: Ah, for some reason I read $p$ as $n$....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The quickest way is using integral:
$$
\lim \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^p}{n^p}\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1 x^pdx=\frac{1}{p+1}.
$$
Seeing this, you may find an elementary proof from
$$
k^p\sim \frac{1}{p+1}\bigg[(k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1}\bigg].
$$

Comment: That's very nice!

Answer (score 8):

Prove by induction on $p$ that $$f_p(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n k^p$$

is a polynomial of degree $p+1$ with leading term $$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

Immediately conclude the limit is $$\frac{1}{p+1}$$

---

Alternatively, use Stolz Cesaro, to show your limit is the same as $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{p}}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}$$

Then use that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\alpha}-1}x=\alpha$$