# Using Stolz Cesaro theorem to show $\lim(1^p+2^p+...+n^p)/(n^{p+1})=1/(p+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know Stolz-Cesaro theorem, and I'm supposed to use this to prove that

$\lim(1^p+2^p+...+n^p)/(n^{p+1})=1/(p+1)$

So I made two sequences, $(x_n)$ which is:

$\sum_{i=1}^n i^p$

And $(y_n)$ which is $n^{p+1}$

So I'm trying to prove $\lim(x_{n+1}- x_n)/ (y_{n+1}-y_n)$

And after some work I get to

$1/(1-((n/n+1)^p)$,

But I don't know what to do when here. It's possible that this approach isn't even right. $n$ tends to infinity.  Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419765/limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac1p2p-ldotsnpnp1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589274/limit-of-a-riemann-sum-lim-n-to-infty-frac1p2p-ldotsnpnp1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478344/what-is-the-result-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sumn-i-1-iknk1 and other posts linked there.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** After SC you get

$$\frac{(n+1)^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}$$

You probably tried to divide by $(n+1)^p$ but that is unnecessary and makes the problem harder. Just expand $(n+1)^{p+1}=n^{p+1}+(p+1)n^p+\mbox{junk}$ in the denominator and cancel $n^{p+1}-n^{p+1}$

Comment: Why am I allowed to use that?

Comment: @George What do you mean? What do you think you are not allowed to do and why?

Comment: The expansion on the denominator.  I'm sure that it is true, I've just never seen it before so I wonder where it comes from is what I mean

Comment: @George http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: @George Or just multiply $(n+1)(n+1)...(n+1)$ by expanding. Note that what you get if you expand is a $n^{p+1}$, when you chose $n$ from each bracket, some $n^p$ when you chose $p$ n's and one one, and smaller degree terms. How many $n^p$ do you get?

Comment: @N.S. What can I do with the remaining junk then?