# Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n k^p}{n^{p+1}}\right)$= $\left(\frac{1}{p+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know how to prove the case when $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}$$\left(\frac{1} {n^{p}}\right)$ if p>0 but $\sum_{i=1}^n k^p$ it is causing me some problems , and the problem does not give me any clue.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419765/limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac1p2p-ldotsnpnp1?lq=1

Comment: where does $i$ and $k$ relate in the sum?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the sum as
$$\frac1n\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl(\frac kn\Bigr)^p\biggr)$$
One gets an upper Riemann sum for the function $x^p$.